# Adding Button outside Tree View Odoo 13

Tags: user-interface, button, treeview, odoo, odoo-13

Good day!

Is there a way to add a button above the Tree View in Odoo? 
I would like to run a function whenever the User Clicks the button. 
If this is not possible can you help me with an alternative?

here is my code on view:

```
'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="account_payment_import_view_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account.payment.import.view.tree</field>
        <field name="model">account.payment.import</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Payment Imports" decoration-info="payment_id != False" decoration-danger="error_msg != False">
                <field name="transaction_date"/>
                <field name="facts_id"/>
                <field name="paid_in_lei"/>
                <field name="paid_in_euro"/>
                <field name="amount"/>
                <field name="account"/>
                <field name="account_no"/>
                <field name="document_no"/>
                <field name="details_bk_statement"/>
                <field name="error_msg"/>
                <field name="invoice_number" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="payment_id" widget="many2onebutton" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="invoice_id" widget="many2onebutton" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="company_id" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="currency_id" invisible="1"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="account_payment_import_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Payment Imports</field>
        <field name="res_model">account.payment.import</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
        <field name="domain">[]</field>
        <field name="context">{'edit': 0}</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem
        id="account_payment_import_menu"
        name="Payment Imports"
        action="account_payment_import_action"
        parent="account.menu_finance_receivables"
        sequence="160"/>
</odoo>'''
```

Comment: Alternative: Action Menu Server Action. There are already examples in Odoo, e.g. "Mark Quotation as sent" in tree views of `sale.order`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, here's my attempt to get the button in the tree view. I'll try to explain you well step by step.

First we have to add the button to the tree view via qweb, inheriting the tree view from the web module.
This will make our new button appear in all tree views, which we don't want. So to avoid that we add a condition `t-if='widget.modelName == "account.payment.import"'` which will cause the button to be generated only for the views whose model is the one that interests us. We also add a CSS class `oe_new_custom_button` to be able to identify the button from the javascript.

Let's call the file that contains this qweb **tree_view_button.xml** and place it in **your_module_name/static/src/xml**.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<templates>
    <t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
        <t t-jquery="div.o_list_buttons" t-operation="append">
            <button type="button" t-if='widget.modelName == "account.payment.import"'
                    class="oe_new_custom_button btn btn-primary">Custom Button
            </button>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

Second we must give functionality to the button, we achieve this through javascript.

Here we inherit the tree view controller, called ListController, whose its role is to render and bind all extra buttons/pager in the control panel, among other things.

Let's call the file that contains this javascript **tree_view_button.js** and place it in **your_module_name/static/src/js**.

```js
odoo.define('your_module_name.tree_view_button', function (require){
    "use strict";

    var ajax = require('web.ajax');
    var ListController = require('web.ListController');

    ListController.include({
        renderButtons: function($node) {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            var self = this;
            if (this.$buttons) {
                $(this.$buttons).find('.oe_new_custom_button').on('click', function() {
                    //custom code
                });
            }
        },
    });
});
```

Finally, we add our javascript to the odoo assets and configure the **manifest** to take all our changes.

Let's call the file that contains the assets **assets.xml** and place it in **your_module_name/views**.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" name="your_module_name_assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/your_module_name/static/src/js/tree_view_button.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

And that's what it should look like ****manifest**.py**.

```py
{
    'data': [
        [ ... ]
        'views/assets.xml',  # <- important
    ],
    "qweb": ['static/src/xml/*.xml'],  # <- important
}
```

### We already have everything, but now, what can be done from javascript?

A little bit of everything, but the most important thing would be the following.

#### Call a model method

```js
odoo.define('your_module_name.tree_view_button', function (require){
    "use strict";

    var ajax = require('web.ajax');
    var ListController = require('web.ListController');

    var rpc = require('web.rpc')

    ListController.include({
        renderButtons: function($node) {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            var self = this;
            if (this.$buttons) {
                $(this.$buttons).find('.oe_new_custom_button').on('click', function() {
                    rpc.query({
                        model: 'account.payment.import',
                        method: 'some_method',
                        args: [],
                    }).then(function(res){
                        // console.log(res)
                        // self.reload();
                    })
                });
            }
        },
    });
});
```

The first argument of args is a list of the ids you want to appear in the self variable of the **some_method**.

#### Call an action

```js
odoo.define('your_module_name.tree_view_button', function (require){
    "use strict";

    var ajax = require('web.ajax');
    var ListController = require('web.ListController');

    ListController.include({
        renderButtons: function($node) {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            var self = this;
            if (this.$buttons) {
                $(this.$buttons).find('.oe_new_custom_button').on('click', function() {
                    self.do_action('model_name.action_id', {
                        additional_context: {},
                    });
                });
            }
        },
    });
});
```

**additional_context** should be, for example,

```js
{
    'active_id': 1,
}
```

### The end

That's all, I hope it works for you. I attach an image of what the button would look like.

[image: button]

Comment: Hi, Tiki, I need to get the record_id or xml_id inside the template, say need to add another condition along with `modelName`, do you know how can we get that xml_id in JS?

Comment: @Azeez I needed the same thing however I don't think env is acccesible in that context, so after some tinkering around you can do something like this: `<button type="button" t-if="widget.viewType == 'list' and widget.controlPanelProps.action.xml_id == 'your_module.view_name'"`